# SockJS backend solution for JAVA on Server Side without websockets

Tags: java, spring, sockjs, reverse-ajax

I have a need of sending notifications from server to client in a web-application over http. I have come across various technologies like DWR, SSE and SockJS. I ended up choosing SockJS. I am new to `SOCKJS` world.

I am using Javascript on Client Side where as `Spring`, `JAVA` on backend.

On Client side, I am using `sockjs-client` to establish the connection to server side.

I am not sure how should I handle those requests on server side and what dependencies I would have to use for the same ?

I have come across `spring-sockjs-client` but not sure if it uses websockets to connect to client or HTTP ?

In case if there are other options to suffice the requirement, please let me know.

Thanks for the help !!